# Error : No route matches [GET] "/cgi-bin/webscr"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use basic Paypal to fund a task in a Rails crowdfunding project. When I click the fund button for the specific task, I create a new funding form which saves the amount the user chooses to fund, ...etc. On the new funding action however, when the user clicks Fund, I want Paypal to process the funding. However,
I am currently getting the error: **"No route matches [GET] "/cgi-bin/webscr"**

Here is **my funding controller:**

```
class FundingsController < ApplicationController
def new
if params[:todo_item_id]
  @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:todo_item_id])
  @funding =  Funding.new
  #(todo_item: @todo_item, user_id: current_user.id)
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @todo_item.nil?
end

end

def create
  @funding = Funding.new(funding_params)
if @funding.save
  redirect_to @funding.paypal_url(funding_path(@funding))
else
  render :new
end
end


protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
def hook
params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
status = params[:payment_status]
if status == "Completed"
  @funding = Funding.find params[:invoice]
  @funding.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], funded_at: Time.now
 end
 render nothing: true
 end


private

def funding_params
  params.require(:funding).permit(:todo_item_id, :user_id, :amount)
end
end
```

Here is my Funding model:

```
 class Funding < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :card
 belongs_to :todo_item
 has_one :user

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :card

def payment_method
if card.nil? then "paypal"; else "card"; end
end
serialize :notification_params, Hash
def paypal_url(return_path)
values = {
    business: "mybusinesssandbox@gmail.com",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
    invoice: id,
    amount: self.amount,
    item_name: self.todo_item.content,
    item_number: self.todo_item.id,
    quantity: '1',
    notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
}
"#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
 end
 end
```

I am not sure why this routing is not working for me . Also, here is my   **app/views/fundings/new.html.erb:**:

```
  <h1><strong>Task:</strong> <%=@todo_item.content%><br>
  <strong>Project:</strong> <%= @todo_item.todo_list.title%> </h1>
  <%= form_for @funding, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :todo_item_id, value: @todo_item.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.label :amount, "Amount you wish to donate in $" %>
  <%= f.number_field :amount %>
  <%= submit_tag "Fund", class: 'btn btn_primary' %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", todo_list_path(@todo_item.todo_list_id, @todo_i), class: 'btn' %><br>
  <%end%>
```

Where did I get it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "No route matches [GET] "/cgi-bin/webscr"

You are requesting this resource to your server, not Paypal. Recheck this:

```
"#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
```

The `Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host` may be blank!

Comment: And for Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host does localhost:3000 sound right in development ?